# How to restrict one post in one category in wordpress 5.2

Tags: wordpress

I'm using Gutenberg editor and managed wordpress server so all old coding is not working in updated wordpress version. So can anyone help me how to restrict one category for one post? I've got a code that was 7 years old, so I don't think that will work. I've got a old code from here:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/select-only-one-category-1/

Comment: Please include the code you are using here in your question.

Comment: Hi Debajit Your query is not clear. Do you need to print only single category of a post? Please let me know to give u an answer.